# Spring JDBCTemplate: is it okay to call a DAO method inside RowMapper?

Tags: java, spring, dao

Let's say we have an object within an object. Say we have database table car that references an owner_id, and the owner table.

Our domain object car references Person:

```
public class Car {
    public class Person person;
}
```

So assuming we have a DAO for Car, and a DAO for Person, is it okay to autowire PersonDao inside CarDao, and query for the Person from within the RowMapper of the CarDao and add it to the car object? I tested this and it works, but I'm asking more if it's considered bad form or practice and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO it's not a good practice. If you want to extract one to many relation from the DB you can use `ResultSetExtractor`.

```
public class MasterDetailResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor {

  @Override
  public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Master m = new Master();
    m.setFirstName(rs.getString(1));
    m.setLastName(rs.getString(2));

    //put the master in a map

    Detail d = new Detail();
    d.setSomeProp(rs.getString(3));

    //check if the master is in the map
        //if yes - add the detail to the master
        //if no - add the master first
    return m;
  }

}
```

The ResultSet is the result of JOIN of the tables.

Comment: Which approach is better... your or Gabriel's. Using Resultsetmapper we pull down a lot of redundant data but only make one trip to the database.

Comment: The RowMapper gives you only one row of the result-set. With Gabriel's approach if one person have 2 or more cars you will end up with a Person object for every car he/she has even if it's the same data. + with ResultSetExtractor you can use only one call to the DB(same sql as in the other answer) I vote for my approach :)

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely categorize it as bad-ish form because database calls should be singular.

You could try calling the DAOs separetly and composing your Car instances from both calls

```
List<Car> cars = carDao.getCars();
List<Person> people = personDao.getPeople();
for (int i=0; i<cars.size(); i++){
    cars.get(i).setPerson(people.get(i));
}
```

or create a join query that generates all the results you need and inside the RowMapper create the appropiate objects:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT c.name, c.serialNumber, p.name FROM Car c INNER JOIN Person p ON c.id = p.carId", .., .., new RowMapper<Car> {
    public Car mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        String carName = rs.getString(1);
        String carSerialNumber = rs.getInt(2);
        String personName = rs.getString(3);
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setName(carName);
        car.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(personName);
        car.setPerson(person);
        return car;
    }
});
```

NOTE: I wrote the code as-is and haven't tested it, but nevertheless this is the way I would go with JDBC.